# Routing between local-only Postfix server and Exchange server

Tags: postfix, exchange

I am trying to forward emails from my Exchange server (ex.domain.local) which can receive emails to a Centos 7/Postfix server (postfix.domain.local) so they can be parsed for a local web application I am working on.

This postfix server doesn't need to reach the outside world, it only needs to receive email from the ex.domain.local server which is in the same subnet.

I can test the postfix server against itself and it receives email, but if I try to send an email from ex.domain.local to my test account (test@postfix.domain.local) it will not go through.

Do I need to have MX records created for the local-only postfix.domain.local server? What is the best way to do this?

I do have A records for each server on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Send connector:

- route mail through smart host -> IP address of postfix.domain.local
- address space -> postfix.domain.local
- source server -> Exchange server